# faster method of copying image data

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have the following script

```
// copy image data to secondary canvas
var pixelData = contextSource.getImageData(x - (lineWidth/2), y - (lineWidth/2), lineWidth, lineWidth);
var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
tmpCanvas.width = tmpCanvas.height = lineWidth;
var tmpContext = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');

tmpContext.putImageData(pixelData, 0, 0);

contextDest.save();
contextDest.arc(x, y, (lineWidth/2), 0, 2*Math.PI);
contextDest.clip();
contextDest.drawImage(tmpCanvas, x - (lineWidth/2), y - (lineWidth/2));
contextDest.restore();
```

the script is sampling image data from canvas source when mouse is moving over the source, then copy it to destination. the script is working good, but a bit slow. here is the result when i move the mouse pointer a bit faster.

[image]

is there any faster method than mine? please help

Comment: basically, when you do things like the above, you do not copy circles. you copy a line where the start/end of the line are those circles.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/1rrpjvsr/) is an example for what i mean, i hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**@Banana has a good point.**

Instead of drawing just the mouse positions, try connecting the positions into a single continuous line..

If you want the rounded effect in your illustration, you can set:

```
context.lineCap='round';
context.lineJoin='round';
```

**As to masking faster...**

A much faster way of masking your image is to:

- draw your single line on the second canvas.
- Use compositing to make all new draws be visible only where existing pixels are opaque. This compositing is 'source-in' and is set using: `context.globalCompositeOperation='source-in'`
- Draw your image onto the second canvas.  The image will show only where the line was.

Using compositing is *much faster* because compositing is hardware accelerated and is optimized by the browser.

That compositing code might look like this:

```
function draw(){
    // clear the second canvas
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

    // draw your continuous line 
    ctx1.beginPath();
    ctx1.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
    for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
        p=points[i];
        ctx1.lineTo(p.x,p.y);
    }
    ctx1.stroke();

    // set compositing so new draws only appear in 
    // existing opaque pixels
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';

    // draw the image
    // the image will only be visible in the exising line
    ctx1.drawImage(img,0,0);

    // be tidy! return compositing to its default mode
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
}
```

Here's an example and Demo:

```js
var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

var isDown=false;
var startX;
var startY;

var points=[];
var cw,ch;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/tempHouse%201.jpg";
function start(){
  cw=canvas.width=canvas1.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=canvas1.height=img.height;

  ctx1.lineCap = "round";
  ctx1.lineJoin = "round";
  ctx1.lineWidth=20;

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
}


function draw(){
  // clear the second canvas
  ctx1.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  // draw your continuous line 
  ctx1.beginPath();
  ctx1.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
    p=points[i];
    ctx1.lineTo(p.x,p.y);
  }
  ctx1.stroke();

  // set compositing so new draws only appear in 
  // existing opaque pixels
  ctx1.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';

  // draw the image
  // the image will only be visible in the exising line
  ctx1.drawImage(img,0,0);

  // be tidy! return compositing to its default mode
  ctx1.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  points.length=0;
  points.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  isDown=false;
  draw();
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  points.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
  isDown=false;
  draw();
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  points.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
  draw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: wow awesome! this is what i looking for..i will try this for sure. thanks a lot, you save my day